# SharePoint REST API filter based on Today's date only and not time. (Similar to IncludeTimeValue=False in CAML query)

Tags: sharepoint-rest-api

I am trying to get data from SharePoint list with REST API that are created today only.

```
var listName = "Carousel%20News";
var today = new Date().toISOString();
```

Here is my REST URL :

```
_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listName + "')/items?$select=Id,Title&$filter=Created eq '" + today + "'";
```

**But when I use this rest URL, I am not getting the items that are created today.**

**(I have double checked that there are items present in the list with the today's created date)**

**My assumption is that, this URL filters based on Date and also Time value.**

**So is there way that I can use REST filter with today's date only and ignore the time stamp (like we do `IncludeTimeValue=False` in CAML query)?**

Answer (score 2):

For filtering date values add *datetime* in filter

```
var listName = "Carousel%20News";
var today = new Date();
var nextday  = moment(today).add(1,'days');

today = moment(today).format("YYYY-MM-DD");
var currentDate = today+'T00:00:00.000Z';

nextday = moment(nextday).format("YYYY-MM-DD");
var nextDate = nextday+'T00:00:00.000Z';
_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listName + "')/items?$select=Id,Title&$filter=Created ge datetime'" +currentDate+ "' and Created le datetime'" +nextDate+ "'";
```

I think this will solve the problem
Note: Refer [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) for next day
Check this in your browser `SITE_URL/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('LISTNAME')/items?$select=Id,Title&$filter=Created ge datetime'2017-09-14T00:00:00.000Z'`

Comment: I already tried using `datetime`. But it didn't solve my problem :)

Comment: updated answer its working for me